# Телефон в качестве модема и точки доступа, устройства в одной локальной сети

Tags: android, windows, wifi, модемы

Android-смарт подключен к компьютеру в качестве USB-модема. И он же (смарт) действует в качестве точки доступа wi-fi для ноутбука. Вопрос: Можно это считать одной локальной сетью для пк и ноутбука? Если нет, то можно её организовать?

Answer (score 0):

Скиньте настройки сети из ноута и компа. Нужен ip/маска/основной шлюз. возможно в вашем случае поможет прописать маршруты. Но для этого и нужна дополнительная информация. если ОС на обоих устройствах Windows то из командной строки выполните ipconfig /all.

Если хотите разобраться с проблемой сами присмотритесь с команде route add.
[https://vladimirmalikov.com/команда-route-add-в-windows/](https://vladimirmalikov.com/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-route-add-%D0%B2-windows/) через нее можно строить маршруты для разных подсетей.

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что у Вас разная адресация для разных сетей(wifi и usb) маской отсекается доступ устройствам друг для друга. Как раз таки для доступа и нужно прописать маршруты на двух устройствах. Не знаю как поведет себя телефон, но в коммутаторах работает :)